# C const global memory seg fault (on address which exists)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I am working on a chess engine, and have a lot of pre-computed values stored in lookup tables.  I put these values into a (very large) 'magic_numbers.c' file (from the algorithm named magic bitboards), and declare them as global const memory.  These values are never changed during the execution of the program.

I recently ran into a seg. fault which was rather odd.  (Firstly, it was odd because it hung my entire computer!)  But more importantly, the address was completely accessable (note the GDB output below).

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    [Switching to Thread 0x7ffe8dd77700 (LWP 9001)]
    0x000000000040c9b9 in magic_get_king_moves (occ=0, square=28 '\034') at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/magic.h:107
    107     return magic_king_moves[square];
    (gdb) p magic_king_moves[28]
    $1 = 241461362688
    (gdb) p bitboard_print(magic_king_moves[28])
    Bitboard
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . 1 1 1 . .
     . . . 1 1 1 . .
     . . . 1 1 1 . .
     . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . .
    $2 = void
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x000000000040c9b9 in magic_get_king_moves (occ=0, square=28 '\034')
        at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/magic.h:107
    #1  pawn_eval_init (board=0x7ffe8dd76e20, pe=0x7ffe8dd70fc0) at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/pawn.c:41
    #2  pawn_eval_probe (ptt=ptt@entry=0x7ffe780008d0, board=board@entry=0x7ffe8dd76e20)
        at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/pawn.c:12
    #3  0x000000000040ab6b in evaluate (board=0x7ffe8dd76e20, search=0x7ffe780008c0)
        at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/evaluate.c:384
    #4  0x00000000004063ef in qsearch (alpha=-1000000000, beta=293, depth=-2, checks_depth=12583424, 
        search=0x7ffe780008c0) at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/search.c:63
    #5  0x0000000000406576 in qsearch (alpha=-293, beta=1000000000, depth=3868, checks_depth=12583424, 
        search=0x7ffe780008c0) at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/search.c:148
    #6  0x0000000000406576 in qsearch (alpha=-1000000000, beta=1000000000, depth=2349, checks_depth=12583424, 
        checks_depth@entry=0, search=0x7ffe780008c0) at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/search.c:148
    #7  0x0000000000404e57 in do_evaluation_thread (params=0x7fffffffdd68)
        at /home/jordan/Projects/thekingsmen/tweaker.c:299
    #8  0x00007ffff78c0374 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
    #9  0x00007ffff6d9027d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

This does happen when I turn off threading as well.

I've run the program through valgrind's memcheck and it does not report anything suspicious.

The seg. fault does go away when I turn off optimizations, so I'm inclined to think it is undefined behavior somewhere, but I still don't understand why it would fail to access memory that I can access from within GDB.

EDIT:  The memory is declared in the file "magic_numbers.c" as:

```
    const bitboard_t magic_king_moves[0x40] = {
    0x303,
    0x707,
    0xe0e,
    0x1c1c,
    0x3838,
    0x7070,
    0xe0e0,
    ...
```

With bitboard_t being a typedef'd uint64_t.

This code is auto-generated by a separate tool I have been working on.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Notice the `\034` (which is char `"`). Are you sure square is exactly `28` as an integer and you haven't got some "out of bounds" exceptions ?

Comment: Yea I am positive.  The square number is between 0 and 63 (inclusive), so a king at square 28 is possible.  (Now, why a king would wonder up that far is another question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found the bug exactly yet, but it is pretty clear what is happening from the GDB output above.  The 'depth' parameter at stack frame #6 is insane, as is the 'checks_depth'.  Something is overwriting values on the stack (at arbitrary points, it seems), which caused it to overwrite the return address.

The seg fault didn't happen in accessing the memory, but in trying to return to the point where it was.

Funny talking about a stack overflow on stack overflow :)